# How to sync the line to line flow of two methods in testng parallel execution?

Tags: selenium, synchronization, testng

I have two methods as shown below.
I'm executing the suite using `testng.xml` by keeping `thread-count="2" parallel="methods"` so that all `@Test` methods will be executed parallelly.

```
 @Test
 //this method will be executed in firefox 
 public void method1(){
     WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("https://google.co.in");
     line2;
     line3;
 }

  @Test
 //this method will be executed other window of firefox
 public void method2(){
     WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("https:gmail.com");  //has to be executed only after the opening of google in method1
     line2;  //has to be executed after the line2 of method1
     line3;  //has to be executed after the line3 of method1
 }
```

Two methods will run parallelly without depending on each other. But as per my requirement (mentioned in the code comments) is it possible to make the execution of method2 to depend on the execution of method1?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below dependsOnMethods in @Test

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" })
public void method2(){
       .....
}
```

Comment: ..here dependsOnMethods will run the second method only after the complete execution of method1. But I want a synchronization between line1 of method 1 to line 1 of method 2 and so on i.e., line1 of method2 should be executed only after the execution of line1 of method1. Please comment again for any clarification.

Comment: If it is the case, you have to write your own synchronization logic in both the methods. Acquire a lock in method 1 and execute the logic and release the lock. Till you release the lock method 2 will wait to acquire a lock.